# Arrays of single-element arrays in Python: why?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, scipy

I came across an oddity when loading a .mat-file created in Matlab into Python with `scipy.io.loadmat`. I found similar 'array structures' being alluded to in other posts, but none explaining them. Also, I found ways to work around this oddity, but I would like to understand *why* Python (or `scipy.io.loadmat`) handles files this way.

Let's say I create a cell in Matlab and save it:

```
my_data = cell(dim1, dim2);
% Fill my_data with strings and floats...
save('my_data.mat','my_data')
```

Now I load it into Python:

```
import scipy.io as sio
data = sio.loadmat('my_data.mat')['my_data']
```

Now `data` has type `numpy.ndarray` and `dtype` `object`. When I look at a slice, it might look something like this:

```
data[0]
>>> array([array(['Some descriptive string'], dtype='<U13'),
           array([[3.141592]]), array([[2.71828]]), array([[4.66920]]), etc.
           ], dtype=object).
```

*Why* is this happening? Why does Python/sio.loadmat create an array of single-element arrays, rather than an array of floats (assuming I remove the first column, which contain strings)?

I'm sorry if my question is basic, but I'd really like to understand what seems like an unnecessary complication.

Comment: How do you fill `my_data` within Matlab?

Comment: In MATLAB there is no such thing as an variable that is not an array. A single valued variable is a 1x1 matrix. A cell is an array that can contain whatever in MATLAB. I am assuming that this behaviour comes from having a cell with numerical values on it and loading that in python. Do you need a cell in MATLAB? if you save it as a matrix you will avoid this behaviour.

Comment: I second @AnderBiguri. A cell in Matlab can take *anything* as element. Similarly, a `dtype=object` array can take *anything* as element. `loadmat` simply is not smart enough to figure out that all the *anything*s are floats in the particular case. Best try not to use cells and objects arrays at all.

Comment: @AnderBiguri and kazemakase: Thank you both for your answers. So, every variable in MATLAB is a matrix, and, therefore, is treated as a separate np.array in Python. My original code used cells for saving timeseries, strings and single variables in the same 'structure'. Changed it to a single matrix now and it works a treat. Thanks!

Comment: @Szabolcs: I filled it as you would a cell, for instance:
`my_data{1,1} = 'A string';`
`my_data{1,2} = 1.23456;`

Comment: @A.Debugne no, the reason is treated as a separate np.array is because you stored it in a cell.

Comment: Just as I suspected :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments:

This behaviour comes because you are saving a cell, an "array" that can contain anything inside. You fill this with matrices of size 1x1 (floats).

That is what python is giving you. an `nparray` of `dtype=object` that has inside 1x1 arrays.

Python is doing exactly what MATLAB was doing. For this example, you should just avoid using cells in MATLAB.